# How to insert data into MongoDB server and display on html table without reload / refresh webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I created a form application for inserting and selecting data from the MongoDB server, using NodeJS, express and EJS template engine.
When I click the submit button for inserting data or displaying data into an HTML table, my webpage refresh; Thus it is the problem of my form application and I don't know how to solve it, so by solving this issue you will do a great help for me, and I really thankful.

registration.ejs

```
    <%- include('../includes/head.ejs')%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/forms.css">
</head>
<body>
    <%- include('../includes/header.ejs')%>
    <main class="content">
        <form class="product-form" action="/" method="post">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="major">Major</label>
                <input type="text" name="major" id="major">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            </div>
            <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="postData(this)">Submit</button>
        </form>
<br><hr><br><br>
        <table border="2"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Full-Name</th>
                    <th>Major</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%
                if(students.length>0){
                    let i=0;
                    for(s of students){
                        i++
                        %>
                        <tr>
                            <th><%= i %></th>
                            <th><%= s.fullname %></th>
                            <th><%= s.major %></th>
                            <th><%= s.email %></th>
                        </tr>
                        <%
                    }
                }
                %>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </main>
    <script src="/js/data.js"></script>
    <%- include('../includes/end.ejs')%>
```

data.js

```
postData = (data) => {
    const fullname = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
    const major = document.getElementById('major').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;


    let url = "http://localhost:3000/";
      let method = 'POST'

    fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            fullname: fullname,
            major: major,
            email: email
        })
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
          throw new Error('Creating or editing a post failed!');
        }
        return res.json();
      })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({
          isEditing: false,
          editPost: null,
          editLoading: false,
          error: err
        });
      });
}
```

Students.js Model

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = Mongoose.Schema;

const studentSchema = new Schema({
    fullname: String,
    email: String,
    major: String
})

module.exports = Mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema)
```

register.js controller

```
const Students = require('../Models/Students');

exports.getAddStudent = (req, res) => {
      Students.find()
      .then((students)=>{
        res.render('./registration/registration.ejs',{
            pagetitle:"Student Registration",
            path:"/form",
            students:students
        });
      }).catch(err=>console.log(err))    
}

exports.postAddStudent = (req, res) => {
        const fullname= req.body.fullname;
        const email= req.body.email;
        const major= req.body.major;

        const students = new Students({
            fullname: fullname,
            email: email,
            major: major
        });
        students
          .save()
          .then(result => {
            res.status(201).json({
              message: 'Post created successfully!',
              post: result
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            if (!err.statusCode) {
              err.statusCode = 500;
            }
            next(err);
          });
}
```

register.js router

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express();
const registrationController = require('../controllers/register');

router.get('/',registrationController.getAddStudent);
router.post('/',registrationController.postAddStudent);

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path")
const body_parser = require('body-parser');
app.use(body_parser.json())
const ejs=require('ejs');
const registration = require("./routes/register");
const connection = require('mongoose');

app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.set('view engine','ejs')

app.use(registration);

connection.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/StudentsRegistration')
.then(()=>{
    app.listen(3000); 
})
.catch(err => console.log);
```

Comment: The basic idea is: catch the form's `submit` event, call `.preventDefault()` on it, then post the data using `fetch()`. The endpoint you use for that should return either just the table data or the table HTML (as opposed to render a full page); this data is then inserted into the page (probably replacing the current table as a whole). You should also start using indentation, since it greatly increases the readability of your code (and therefore the chances of people helping you).

Comment: Just throwing this out, but indentation is pretty important. How your code examples sit, it makes me not want read it and go to a different question.

Comment: It sounds like you've never used `fetch()`? In that case we'd just be writing the code for you because you're lacking the knowledge how to use the one crucial technique you need to solve this. Learn about fetch first, there's really nothing else I can suggest at this point.